# Can I use MSSQL2005 Management Studio to login to MSSQL2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

Can I use MSSQL2005 Management Studio to login to MSSQL2008 Express?

Is that a must for me to install MSSQL 2008 Express?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, SQL Server 2005 Management Studio can NOT connect to SQl Server 2008. I've just tried it and I get an error message that SQL Server 2005 Management Studio can only connect to SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005.

Comment: That's what I was about to write in my answer because that is the message I recalled. Then I checked it, and it worked (might be a fix in one of the SQL 2005 service packs).

Comment: OK. I'll update my install and see what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

2005 Management Studio will connect to SQL Server 2008 (standard in this case) so I expect the answer is yes.

But, unless you can find something definitive, you need to validate.